# Midori Segmentation Fault

Tags: web-browsers, midori

Since a while (approx. 1 month) now midori is not starting anymore and gets a `segmentation fault`. Yesterday I updated the firmware and software to the latest versions, still no change. I also tried to remove and reinstall it with purge.

I also compiled https://code.google.com/p/minimal-web-browser/ with the same result on that browser. It might be a webkit problem. I know there was also an issue one year ago, but it should be resolved by now.

I have no idea what else to do.

### EDIT

I removed all Webkit packages that I found and installed midori again and now it works.

Comment: is there anymore information/detail on the error other than `segmentation fault`? stack trace or log file?

Comment: it just prints: `zsh: segmentation fault  midori`, I didn't find out if and where midori stores logs.

Answer (score 1):

Midori is under heavy development, and it looks like this is just a bug related to improper handling of memory.  I would compile the latest git daily with a cron script to make sure you get a version that doesn't contain that bug as soon as it comes out.

1. Create a script to update Midori daily.  Add these lines to it:

   ```
   sudo git clone git://git.xfce.org/kalikiana/midori
   cd midori/
   sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr && make
   sudo checkinstall
   cd ../
   sudo rm -rf midori/
   ```
2. To edit your crontab file, type the following command at the UNIX / Linux shell prompt:

   ```
   $ crontab -e
   ```
3. Add your script to the list.  Be wary of the syntax that cron follows. Here is an easy to remember format:

   ```
   * * * * * command to be executed
   - - - - -
   | | | | |
   | | | | ----- Day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
   | | | ------- Month (1 - 12)
   | | --------- Day of month (1 - 31)
   | ----------- Hour (0 - 23)
   ------------- Minute (0 - 59)
   ```

   So, to update Midori five minutes after midnight, every day, enter:

   ```
   5 0 * * * /path/to/script.sh
   ```

Comment: I use Kweb now, so I can not confirm what you are saying. What I could find out and also added in my edit was that the problem should be related to some webkit libraries that get corrupted for unknown reasons on the pi.